# What is a geometry image?

Tags: image, 3d, geometry, mesh, parameterization

What are geometry images and how can I create them ?
It's a little weird ...
I need to create geometry images from mesh models and vice versa.

[Sample Geometry Image + Normal Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqAR0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Geometry images are a way of encoding shapes.  They were introduced in [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/hoppe/gim.pdf).

To quote from the introduction:

> [A geometry image] captures geometry as a simple n × n array of [x,
>   y,z] values. Other surface attributes, such as normals and colors, are
>   stored as additional square images, sharing the same domain as the
>   geometry. Because the geometry and attributes share the same
>   parametrization, the parametrization itself is implicit — “texture
>   coordinates” are absent. Moreover, this parametrization fully utilizes
>   the texture domain (with no wasted space). Geometry images can be
>   encoded using traditional image compression algorithm, such as wavelet
>   based coders. Also, geometry images are ideally suited for hardware
>   rendering. They may be transmitted to the graphics pipeline in a
>   compressed form just like texture images. And, they eliminate
>   expensive pointer-based structures such as indexed vertex lists.

Comment: Thanks .. I saw it but cannot understand ... What is this "parametrization"? Can anyone explain more ?

Comment: @Rostamiani, it is the same as texture coordinates, which you can Google.